# Generate random color on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to generate a random color every time I hover over my box. Now, it will only generate a random color one time.

Here is my Jquery: https://jsfiddle.net/Mulk/q0hxw0yd/#&togetherjs=uB54KHo5BN

This is my code so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * (255 - 0) + 0);
    var g = Math.floor(Math.random() * (255 - 0) + 0);
    var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * (255 - 0) + 0);
    var color = "rgb("+r+","+g+","+b+")"

    $("#container").hover(function(){
        $(this).css("background-color", color);
        }, function(){
        $(this).css("background-color", color);
    });

});
```

Comment: You have to put the code that generates the color **inside** the event handler

Comment: out of curiosity why `(255 -0) + 0` why not only `255`?

Comment: @ImranAli I agree with You. Nobody is mentioning this moment. So it's very sad that new generation of "developers" does not know elementary math. That's a shame!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to put the color generation INSIDE the hover() function, so that it generates a new color on each hover event: https://jsfiddle.net/q0hxw0yd/3/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#container").hover(function(){
      var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
      var g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
      var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
      var color = "rgb("+r+","+g+","+b+")"
      $(this).css("background-color", color);
  });
});
```

Also: as users have commented, `(255 - 0) + 0` is equivalent to `255`... not sure why that was in the original code!

Comment: Thank You. I thought it would be way more complicated

Comment: Lol totally missed that - others have commented on the main question also :P Have edited the answer to reflect that!

Answer (score 1):

Here you are:

```
var color =  "#" + Math.random().toString(16).slice(2, 8);
```

Comment: This may produce less than 6 hex digits.

Comment: @Oriol I've played with this variables, but did not get where it may happen. Really. Math.random generates random number, toString([radix]) converts result to string, where radix - an integer between 2 and 36 specifying the base to use for representing numeric values. and slice takes 8 characters of resulting string. I've checked many times, randomized values are so long that it always will have 8 elements to extract from it.

Comment: @num8er "*randomized values are so long that it always will have 8 elements*" is completely false. For example, if `Math.random()` returns `0`, the result will be `"#"`. If it returns `0.5`,  it will be `#8`. And so on. Most numbers will be long enough, but some will break your code.

Comment: @Oriol how possible that it may happen?

Comment: @num8er Hard to say. `Math.random` is implementation-dependent, the spec only enforces the result to be >= 0 and < 1. So if an implementation decides to always return `0`, this code will always fail.

Answer (score 1):

This help you :

```html
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">This is Div</div>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#container").hover(function(){
                var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
                var g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
                var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
                 var color = 'rgb(' + r + ',' + g + ',' + b + ')';
                 $(this).css("background-color",color);
                })
                
            });
        </script>
     </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this 2 code examples that handles mouse events and changes both background and text colors to make it readable some ridiculous colors:

```html
<style>
  #container {
    width: 300px; height: 300px;
    text-shadow: 1px 0px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  }
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">This div reacts to mouse move</div>

<script>
  $(function(){
    var $container = $('#container');

    $container.mousemove(function(){
      var rgb = [
        parseInt(Math.random() * 255),
        parseInt(Math.random() * 255),
        parseInt(Math.random() * 255)
      ]; // generating array of Red Green Blue numbers (will be used to change background color)
      $container
        .css('background-color', 'rgb(' + rgb.join(',') + ')')
        .css('color', 'rgb(' + [255-rgb[0], 255-rgb[1], 255-rgb[2]].join(',') + ')');
    });
  });
</script>
```

```html
<style>
  #container {
    width: 300px; height: 300px;
    text-shadow: 1px 0px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  }
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">This div reacts to mouse move</div>

<script>
  $(function(){
    var $container = $('#container');

    $container.hover(function(){
      var rgb = [
        parseInt(Math.random() * 255),
        parseInt(Math.random() * 255),
        parseInt(Math.random() * 255)
      ];
      $container
        .css('background-color', 'rgb(' + rgb.join(',') + ')')
        .css('color', 'rgb(' + [255-rgb[0], 255-rgb[1], 255-rgb[2]].join(',') + ')');
    });
  });
</script>
```